# Definitions (criteria/requirements) of "organic" growing throughout the world

Tags: organic

[The US Department of Agriculture's National Organic Program](http://www.ams.usda.gov/AMSv1.0/nop) has a set of [regulations](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/7/part-205/subpart-C) which determines if an agricultural production can be considered as "organic" or not:

- 205.200 General.
- 205.201 Organic production and handling system plan.
- 205.202 Land requirements.
- 205.203 Soil fertility and crop nutrient management practice standard.
- 205.204 Seeds and planting stock practice standard.
- 205.205 Crop rotation practice standard.
- 205.206 Crop pest, weed, and disease management practice standard.
- 205.207 Wild-crop harvesting practice standard.
- 205.236 Origin of livestock.
- 205.237 Livestock feed.
- 205.238 Livestock health care practice standard.
- 205.239 Livestock living conditions.
- 205.240 Pasture practice standard.
- 205.270 Organic handling requirements.
- 205.271 Facility pest management practice standard.
- 205.272 Commingling and contact with prohibited substance prevention practice standard.

---

Are there similar regulations in other countries?

Comment: A short answer as "yes" is not useful and a more detailed one would have to summarize thousands of pages of legislation from multiple countries in order to keep it exact and unambiguous, providing examples for every factor and also their exceptions. I recommend you edit the question as "growing organic vegetables and fruits in my backyard somewhere in US (EU, India, etc), asking for similar regulations in comparison with the link provided", and I will retract my closure vote as "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean is there an EU equivalent? Yes, I think this [site](https://ec.europa.eu/agriculture/organic/index_en) will give you the info for organic farming in the EU.